# Store dynamic fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm working on a c# MVC5 EF6 project and I'm facing the following situation. I have a project model with some default properties:

```
public class project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to give the user the option to add extra fields. Because I don't know how many fields they will add and what type of field they add, I cannot add free fields to the class like this:

```
public int FreeInt1 { get; set; }
public int FreeInt2 { get; set; }
public string FreeString1 {get; set; }
// etc. (let's hope we have enough fields)
```

So, I think the fields should be dynamically created (and stored per project). I was thinking of two possible solutions:

1. Create an extra table `ProjectFields` in a sort of Key - Value structure like the image below:

[image]

When using this approach, when you have thousands of projects with say at least 10 extra fields, it all adds up very quickly.

2. Add an extra string property to my project class `public string ProjectFields { get; set; }` and create logic to add extra fields in a XML or Json string and save that to the ProjectFields field.

I really don't know if I'm thinking in the right direction or that I should approach this situation in an other way?

Comment: Do you have searching over those fields?

Comment: @GeneR Not right now, but it could be a feature in the future.

Comment: I tried both solutions, and for me `Json` is the best, although u can have some trouble with server-side iteration and database search, but for client-side it is perfect

Answer (score -1):

provide the user with the interface to add columns , store his added column names in an array and use the following logic

```
//if we have an array
// array = ["ID","name","IP","active"];
foreach(var item as array)
{
 sql = "alter table [TABLENAME] add [item] int default 0 NOT NULL"
//run this sql query using sql command and see the magic
}
```

Comment: -1. That is not an answer. The real problem is not manipuating the db schema - but the source of the application and recomping it. EF - the technology the poster uses - can not use dynamically added fields.

Comment: well i could give you the solution to what you  if you asked this politely - but a -1 means no answer at all

Comment: the EF does use dynamic creation and updating of fields at run time along with the datasource and data base

Comment: In what universe? Because my copies of EF - all versions - rely on generated classes that are hard-compiled into the application.

Comment: Absolutely bad solution. You should NEVER allow end-user to modify database structure, and it is bad practise at all to do it runtime.

Comment: in this universe - because they are multiple alternatives to database binding with EF

Comment: Well Mr. @GeneR would be happy to come up with a nice solution

Comment: I would suggest doing what you have described with having a table for project fields however have a table of project values store all values as a varchar(max) and have the user pick a type for the field and enforce constraints of that field type in your application.